# How can I get the name of the current network in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Say I'm connected to `test.server.com` for my Internet access. Is there any way to have that string returned using VBA?

To expand, at your requests (sorry, networking is something I know very little about):

The following refers to Windows 7 Enterprise: If you were to navigate to the 'Network and Sharing Center' within the Control Panel, this would be the name of the 'Domain network'. Alternatively, clicking on the networking icon in the taskbar would show this network name with 'Internet access' beneath it.

Comment: What do you mean by,"connected to a server?"  Within Excel?  Connected for what?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "for my Internet access".  How would you find the information outside of VBA for example?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you can create a userform and place a webbrowser on the control. navigate to `http://whatismyipaddress.com/` There you can extract the ISP Name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the DNS host and/or domain name with [GetComputerNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the Windows base API:

```
Option Explicit

Enum COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT
    ComputerNameNetBIOS
    ComputerNameDnsHostname
    ComputerNameDnsDomain
    ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified
    ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsFullyQualified
End Enum

Declare Function GetComputerNameEx Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetComputerNameExA" ( _
    ByVal NameType As COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT, _
    ByVal lpBuffer As String, _
    ByRef lpnSize As Long) As Long

Sub test()
    Dim buffer As String
    Dim size As Long
    size = 255
    buffer = Space(size)
    GetComputerNameEx ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified, buffer, size
    Debug.Print Left$(buffer, size)
End Sub
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you. It's beyond my ken to dig in and get exactly the result I want without a bit of fiddling, but using your answer I bodged something together. I'll post it as an answer as it's pretty lengthy.

Answer (score 2):

Using user A. Webb's reply, I got it working using the following, which pulls the whole computer name and network and then just pares it down. I'm sure there are prettier methods, but it works.

```
Option Explicit

Enum COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT
    ComputerNameNetBIOS
    ComputerNameDnsHostname
    ComputerNameDnsDomain
    ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified
    ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain
    ComputerNamePhysicalDnsFullyQualified
End Enum

Declare Function GetComputerNameEx Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetComputerNameExA" ( _
ByVal NameType As COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT, _
ByVal lpBuffer As String, _
ByRef lpnSize As Long) As Long

Sub test()

Dim buffer As String
Dim size As Long
Dim network_and_computer As String
Dim network_name As String

size = 255
buffer = Space(size)
GetComputerNameEx ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified, buffer, size
network_and_computer = Left$(buffer, size)

MsgBox network_and_computer

network_name = Right(network_and_computer, Len(network_and_computer) - InStr(1, network_and_computer, ".", vbTextCompare))

MsgBox network_name

End Sub
```

Comment: It is unnecessary to parse out the network name. If that is all you want, just change the `ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified` argument of `GetComputerNameEx` to `ComputerNameDnsDomain`.